# Display Blank values in ssrs reports

Tags: reporting-services

I have values in a column (col 3) in ssrs report which is a calculation of two other columns.
The calculation is col3 = col1/col2 where i set col3 to nothing if col2 is 0.
e.g. iif(col2 = 0,nothing,col1/col2) 
However the col3 should show blank values in report but it shows 0.
The format of col3 is given as "#,0.0%;(#,0.0%)"
Is There any way to display the values as blank when col2 is 0 ?

Comment: Looks like this is the likely solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606390/detecting-null-dates-and-showing-empty-string-in-ssrs

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem when col2 is zero?  [`IIF` doesn't short circuit in SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1204179/1657324), so a zero there should be giving you divide by zero errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yup i found the solution..The solution was not in the syntax but in the format in which i put the solution in expression dialogue box of ssrs.

Initially my solution was :

```
= iif(col2 = 0,nothing, +   
col1/col2)
```

Later I changed my solution to :

```
= iif(col2 = 0,nothing,col1/col2)
```

It worked !